# Why am I unable to use ssh to host from config?

Tags: git, ssh

```
Host devops
    Hostname ssh.dev.azure.com
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
        IdentitiesOnly yes

Host repverse
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/repgithubssh
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I updated my git remote to `git@repverse:User/reponame.git` but when I run `git push origin main`, I keep getting the error

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname repverse: Name or service not known

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong that it doesn't detect the hostname. I restarted ssh service and yet it doesn't work. What can I check? All the ones I found on SO did not resolve the error. Any suggestions on what I can check/try?

I could try to set git config sshCommand ... but I would rather have it done using config file so that I don't have to do this every time I use some repo that requires a separate sshkey. It's easier to simply use the host.

Comment: First `ssh -Tv repverse` If it works — does `git` uses the same `ssh`?

Comment: @phd, Here's what I get: `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname repverse: Name or service not known`. So, it doesn't seem like git is using the same ssh? So, has git been using the default ssh? How can I fix it?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. It was the file ownership error where the ownership was set to `root` instead of the current user.